# Runtime exception thrown by GatewayProxyFactoryBean

Tags: spring-integration

Migrating to Spring Integration **4.0.4**, the following exception is thrown when using a service bean created with `GatewayProxyFactoryBean`:

```
Sep 30, 2014 3:45:21 PM org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils createStandardEvaluationContext
WARNING: Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory
java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanfactory
    at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.createMethodInvocationEvaluationContext(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:182)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.access$000(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper$DefaultMethodArgsMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:279)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper$DefaultMethodArgsMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.mapArgumentsToMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:153)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:103)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:304)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:295)
```

Our design uses `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` extensively and this exception seems to be new.  In this case we are not using any SpEL expressions.   How can this exception be avoided?

Answer (score 7):

Actually it isn't Exception, but just `WARN`.

From one side you can just ignore it or decrease logging level for the `org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils` category.

Or, of course, and what will be better and even recommended, when you create your own `GatewayProxyFactoryBean`, provide for it `BeanFactory` and invoke `afterPropertiesSet()` of that `GatewayProxyFactoryBean`.

Comment: How will decreasing the logging level prevent the exception being thrown?

Comment: You should specify `ERROR` or `FATAL` level for that class. Looks like you are on the WebSphere. There is a `Logging & Trace` page in the Management Web Console.

Comment: There is no exception being thrown, it is simply in the log message to identify the culprit code. A `BeanFactory` is now required wherever SpEL is available, to provide full access to SpEL functionality (specifically `@beanName` resolution). Suppressing the log will work just fine if you don't need that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but as @Artem Bilan suggested, you can do something like this in your log4j.xml file, assuming you are dealing with an appender named console

```
<logger name="org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <level value="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```